# Reacting to a button click right away

Tags: android, multithreading

I am building a snake game, and it works, but with a little bug that really irritates me.
when I click on one of the buttons that in the xml, the snake changes it's direction according to the button.

the problem is that if you have clicked on a button after it's has already re-entered the loop inside the run() of the thread and entered the loop inside the the onDraw() (you can see in the code) it will first finish the loop of the run() and then re-enter and do the turn. and by that a delay is created from the click time to when it turns.

the turn works like this- there is a String variable that gets "LEFT","RIGHT", "UP" or "DOWN", according to what it gets it moves the snake. when you click on a button it changes the variable accoring to what button u have clicked on.

heres the code of how it moves the snake accoring to the direction:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    switch(direction){
    case "RIGHT"
        xLoc=xLoc+PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case "UP"
        yLoc=yLoc-PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case "LEFT"
        xLoc=xLoc-PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case "DOWN"
        yLoc=yLoc+PART_SIZE;
    break;
    }//swich
    int x=xLoc;
    int y=yLoc;
        for(BodyPart bp:WholeBody){
            Rect r=new Rect();
            r.set(0+x, 0+y, PART_SIZE+x, PART_SIZE+y);
            bp.setR(r);
            canvas.drawRect(bp.getR(),bp.getP());
            int xtemp=bp.getX();
            int ytemp=bp.getY();
            bp.setX(x);
            bp.setY(y);
            x=xtemp;
            y=ytemp;
        }//for each 
}//onDraw
```

the xLoc and the yLoc is the location of where the head of the snake will go to, and the its moves each body part(each rect of the snake-each bodypart is an equall rect) the the location of where the bodypart before it was.

here are the onClick()s:

```
 left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"){
            gv.snake.Left();
            }
        }
    });
    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"){
            gv.snake.Right();   
            }
        }
    });
    up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="UP"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"){
            gv.snake.Up();  
            }
        }
    });
    down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="UP"){
            gv.snake.Down();
            }
        }
    });
```

gv is an variable from class gameView which in it has a variable from the class snake

here are the setDirection:

```
public void Left(){
        direction="LEFT";
}
public void Up(){
        direction="UP";
}
public void Right(){
        direction="RIGHT";
}
public void Down(){
        direction="DOWN";
}
```

and here is the run of the thread:

```
public void run() {
        long stepPerSecond=1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while(isRunning){
            Canvas c= null;
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

            try{
                c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
                    this.onDraw(c);
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

            }
            sleepTime= stepPerSecond-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            if(sleepTime>0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            else
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
```

is there someway that there will not be that delay?

maby when you click on a button it will stop the run() and redo it after it had updated the direction variable acording to the click.

Comment: By the look of this, the maximum delay you should notice is the time it takes to render a single frame, combined by the wait time generated by your FPS setting (or 10 milliseconds if you set it to negative for whatever reason).
that means you get a huge 
I don't think you can interrupt the render method, and you definitely can't interrupt the `Thread.sleep` portion of the code.

If you are getting a noticeable delay, either your render code is really slow, or your fps is set really low (which are probably bigger problems)

Comment: why do you call `onDraw()` (and so `canvas.drawRect()`) outside the GUI thread?

Comment: Based on what you said, it appears run() is blocking. Did you try breaking out of run() based on a direction change flag (that you set in all of the direction button clicks). With this you can avoid the blocking done by run().

Comment: Alexei, what is  GUI thread? sorry i am new at programing and Gaurav-if i understang what you are saying correctly then it wouldnt work because the delay is created when u click on a button after it had already restarted the loop, so the flag will have an effect after the loop has ended so its the same as leaving it as it is